# How to exclude a whole group if one record contains a certain value?

Tags: sql, oracle

Here are my tables:

```
TableA      
primarykey  Name    Description 
1           John    Male 
2           Josh    Male 
3           Allen   Male 

TableB      
projectid   Name    Category 
1           John    QB
1           John    RB
1           John    WR
2           Josh    QB
2           Josh    WR
3           Allen   QB
```

And I want a query to combine both tables, but I only want the records if one of the records don't have 'RB'.

I have a general query below

```sql
Select * from TableA a, TableB b, where a.primarykey = projectid
```

```
projectid   Name    Category    Description
1           John    QB          Male
1           John    RB          Male
1           John    WR          Male
2           Josh    QB          Male
2           Josh    WR          Male
3           Allen   QB          Male
```

but I'm not sure how to exclude all the records if it has 'RB'.

This is what I want my results to be:

```
projectid   Name    Category    Description
2           Josh    QB          Male
2           Josh    WR          Male
3           Allen   QB          Male
```

Any tips or suggestions on what to use to try and get this?

Comment: Why is `Name` in both tables? Which is the one you want in your result?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This could be a way to do this using subquery in WHERE clause

```
select b.projectid,b.Name,b.Category,a.Description
from TableA a,TableB b
where a.primarykey=b.projectid   
  and
  a.primarykey <> ( select projectid from tableb b  where b.category ='RB');
```

Comment: Welcome @confusedbeginner

Answer (score 5):

You can make use of not exists with join in this way to make sure you are not getting any ID having 'RB' as category.

```
select t1.projectId, t1.name, t1.category, t.description from tableA  t 
join tableB t1 on t1.projectid = t.primarykey 
where not exists (select 1 from tableB t2 where t1.projectID = t2.projectID and t2.category = 'RB') 
order by t1.projectID ;


PROJECTID   NAME    CATEGORY    DESCRIPTION
 2           Josh      WR        Male
 2           Josh      QB        Male
 3           Allen     QB        Male
```

Comment: Thanks! I totally didn't think of that. This is perfect!